# ng-table inside a custom directive error "Cannot set property '$data' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bindings

here my question:

I am trying to build a directive in angular, which would use an `ng-table` inside.
The problem is that input parameter `tableData` is initialized as an empty array initially because it is set from the outside of the directive when the user clicks on a button.

So i added a watch on the `tableData` and tried to reload the table when the `tableData` changes.

But the differ.resolve functions ends up with the following exception.

Please help

directive usage

```
<table-multiselect table-data="objectArray"></table-multiselect>
```

This is my temp

TableMultiselect.tmpl.cshtml

```
<table ng-table="multiselect" class="table">
     <tr ng-repeat="feature in $data">
            <td data-title="'Id'" sortable="'id'">{{feature .id}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">{{feature .name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Type'" sortable="'type'">{{feature .type}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

controller

```
.directive('TableMultiselect', function (ngTableParams) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'TableMultiselect.tmpl.cshtml',
        scope: {
            tableData: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

            var buildMultiSelectTable = function () {
                return new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 10,
                    sorting: {
                        id: 'asc'
                    },
                    filter: {},

                }, {
                    counts: [10],
                    total: $scope.tableData.length, // length of data
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        var data = $scope.tableData;
                        if (data.length <= 10) {
                            params.settings({ 'counts': [] });
                        }
                        params.total(data.length);
                        $defer.resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            };

            $scope.multiselect = buildMultiSelectTable();

            $scope.$watch('tableData', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if ($scope.tableData != undefined && $scope.tableData.length > 0) {
                   $scope.multiselect.reload();
                }
            });
        },


    };
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null
    at angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:3095
    at l.promise.then.J (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:101)
    at angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:102
    at h.a.$get.h.$eval (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:113)
    at h.a.$get.h.$digest (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:110)
    at h.a.$get.h.$apply (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:113)
    at m (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:72)
    at w (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.B.onreadystatechange (angular?v=M5FbIdPbFPNnbg6slbXZa4DR7EKc6tL5nLLGAVGYAa41:79)
```

Answer (score -1):

One problem that is obvious from the code you have pasted is the directive name should be 'tableMultiSelect' not 'TableMultiSelect'

```
app.directive('tableMultiselect', function (ngTableParams) {
```

There might be other problems which are tough to guess with out looking at the complete code, so here's the working implementation based on what i understood from your question : http://plnkr.co/edit/7MHhl6AKdfzajprfc0xK?p=preview

And this is how your object array changes at runtime.

```
app.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.objectArray = [];

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.objectArray.push({
        id: 1,
        name : "Abc",
        type : "type1"
      });
    },2000);

  });
```